# SQL Server replication - set PollingInterval in sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent

Tags: sql-server, replication

I'm trying to create replication subscriptions to and SQL Server 2008 R2 via a script. There are 3 subscribers so this script creates the subscriptions by calling

sp_addmergesubscription

and then

sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent

with the required parameters for each subscriber. The only thing i haven't accomplished so far is to tell the sp_addmergepushsubscription_agent that i wish to set the PollingInterval to 30 seconds instead of the default 60 seconds. What parameters need to be changed in order to do the trick?

Comment: I can't tell what your question is about, but maybe it belongs to [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Thanks, indeed it seems a more appropriate place. I'll ask it there.